# Spring RestController receive a huge size byteArray As RequestBody leads to not enough memory error

Tags: java, arrays, spring, memory-leaks, inputstream

I have RestApi endpoint that accepts a byte[] as a RequestBody. However, it uses too much memory. How can I read this large byte[] array in?

Are there some better ways to do this?

My current solution that's not working is below:

**Controller:**

```
@RequestMapping(value = "person", method = RequestMethod.POST)public 
void postPerson(@RequestBody() byte[] data) {
  PersonService.postPerson(data);
}
```

**Service:**

```
public void postPerson(byte[] data) {

Splitter sp = new Splitter();

    sp.splitFile(data, (bytes) -> {

    });
}
```

**Interface:**

```
public interface Splitter {
    void splitFile(byte[] data, Consumer<byte[]> segmentConsumer);
}
```

**Splitter:**

```
public void splitFile(byte[] data, Consumer<byte[]> segmentConsumer){

    try {
        XMLInputFactory xmlif = XMLInputFactory.newInstance();
        final XMLEventReader reader = xmlif.createXMLEventReader(new 
        ByteArrayInputStream(data), StandardCharsets.ISO_8859_1.name());

        String fileHeader = "";

        StringBuilder aggregatedSegments = new StringBuilder();
        int segmentCount = 0;

        while (reader.hasNext()) {
            final XMLEvent event = reader.nextEvent();

            if (isStartElement(event, "status")) {
                fileHeader = buildHeader(event, reader);
            }

            if (isStartElement(event, "person")) {
                segmentCount++;
                aggregatedSegments.append(buildSegment(event, reader));
                if (maxNrOfElementsInSegment == segmentCount) {
                    segmentConsumer.accept(buildFile(fileHeader, aggregatedSegments));
                    aggregatedSegments = new StringBuilder();
                    segmentCount = 0;
                }
            }
        }
        if (segmentCount != 0) {
            segmentConsumer.accept(buildFile(fileHeader, aggregatedSegments));
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }    
}
```

Comment: please provide a code snippet for us.

Comment: Take in big byte array in controller make me have to increase the heap. But that is not the long term solution.

Comment: as an FYI, an object annotated with \@Service is used to annotate a spring component tied to a domain model. I don't know if this is what you have. i might annotate this with \@Component instead. it doesn't solve your problem but I thought you should know. [Service Annotation in Spring java docs] (https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/stereotype/Service.html)

Comment: can you provide the exception/stack trace or Error you are seeing?

Comment: it seems this is a good solution. https://boplicity.nl/knowledgebase/spring/Using+HTTP+PUT+and+Spring+MVC+to+upload+files.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
@RequestMapping(value = "", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public void postTransportEvent(HttpServletRequest request) {
File streamedFile = new File("test.xml");

    try {
        InputStream inputStream = request.getInputStream();

        if (inputStream != null) {
            FileOutputStream outputStream = new FileOutputStream(streamedFile);

            byte[] buffer = new byte[10240];
            int bytesRead;

            while ((bytesRead = inputStream.read(buffer)) > 0) {
                outputStream.write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
            }

            outputStream.flush();
            outputStream.close();
        }

        inputFileStream.close();

    } catch (IOException e) {
        log.error(e.toString(), e);
    } finally {
        streamedFile.delete();
    }
```

Comment: i'm wondering, if you don't read `request.getInputStream()`, where does the framework store the actual bytes?